# Determining SFTP issue details by return code

Tags: ftp, sftp, exit-code

We are moving our applications from FTP to SFTP.  We have a utility FTP script (developed in-house) that generally handles all of our FTP needs, and returns exit codes depending upon the type of error encountered (such as 1=Could not connect; 2=source file not found; 3=target directory not found...; 90=some files successful, some not) based largely upon the information found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes.

The script deciphers the 3-digit numeric responses from the FTP server in order to determine its own exit code.

Unless I am missing it (and I hope that's so) it seems that there is no similar capability (numeric response codes) with sftp; the responses I have seen are all text-based, and can therefore vary wildly (if nothing else, due to language/region differences).

Is this a price we pay for "advancement," or is there a reasonable way of emulating the capability we had before?

Thanks for your time.
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

SFTP commands do have error codes internally. Probably they are not made accessible by the tool you use for SFTP. It's also necessary to note that SFTP runs on top of SSH where SSH and SFTP have overlapping error codes (i.e. there exists SSH error 2 and SFTP error 2), so you have to distinguish them somehow.